# Get current resource configuration via adb

Tags: android

How do I get the current resource configuration using adb? I want to know the current values that affect resource loading - for example: orientation, smallest-width, etc.
This way I can more easily debug which resources are being selected from my values-xxx, layout-xxx, drawable-xxx folders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
adb shell dumpsys window | grep mCurConfiguration
```

In my tests, this results in:

```
  mCurConfiguration={0 1.0 ?mcc?mnc en_US ldltr sw800dp w1280dp h775dp 160dpi xlrg land finger -keyb/v/h -nav/h s.88}
```

In this example, the current orientation is "land" and the smallest width is "sw800dp".